# Before being overturned, did Roe v Wade grant pregnant men the right to have abortions, in addition to pregnant women?

Tags: privacy, us-supreme-court, abortion, transgender

The language in the Roe v Wade decision refers over and over to the rights of a "pregnant woman". Does this mean it protected only the rights of pregnant women, and not pregnant men, to procure abortions?

Answer (score 2):

*Roe* and *[Casey](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/505/833/case.pdf)* refer to the category "pregnant woman." But in many places, the reasons talk only about a "person" and the interests that underpin the reasoning would clearly apply to all pregnant people:

- constitutional protection of the decision to terminate one's pregnancy "derives from the Due Process Clause of the Fourteenth Amendment... The controlling word in the cases before us is 'liberty'" (*Casey*, p. 846)
- "Our cases recognize 'the right of the *individual*, married or single, to be free from unwarranted governmental intrusion into matters so fundamentally affecting a person as the decision whether to bear or beget a child.'" (*Casey*, p. 851)
- "the liberty of the woman is at stake in a sense unique to the human condition and so unique to the law. The mother who carries a child to full term is subject to anxieties, to physical constraints, to pain that only she must bear." (*Casey*, p. 852)
- the plurality in *Casey* characterized "*Roe*'s central holding" being that "viability marks the earliest point at which the State’s interest in fetal life is constitutionally adequate to justify a legislative ban on nontherapeutic abortions." (p. 860)
- and so forth